# Can't Install NVIDIA drivers after W10 clean install

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, installation, nvidia-graphics-card

I've upgraded my pc to Windows 10 from Windows 8 thru clean install since windows 8 doesn't have a direct upgrade path. After performing a clean install, obviously, drivers are also removed. I've tried to download NVIDIA drivers from their official site [Here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us). But when I've tried to run the setup and install drivers Nvidia gives me this error:

> NVIDIA Installer cannot continue. This NVIDIA graphics driver is not compatible with this version of Windows. Please update your driver using GeForce Experience to download the correct version.

I've also tried to install drivers thru GeForce Experience but it also gave me the same error

> Installation can't continue: The NVIDIA graphics driver is not compatible with this version of Windows

Specs:
GeForce 630GT
Windows 10 64-Bit build 2004

Edit: Here is the driver I've downloaded

> Manually downloaded:
> -451.67-desktop-win10-64bit-international-dch-whql.exe

> Downloaded by GeForce Experience:
> -GeForce Game Ready Driver: Version 451.67 - Release date: 07/09/2020

EDIT: It seems that GT630 or Fermi Series GPUs has reached its EOL (End of Life) as of April 2018. Security updates is still available until January 2019.

> Effective April 2018, Game Ready Driver upgrades, including performance enhancements, new features, and bug fixes, will be available only on Kepler, Maxwell, and Pascal series GPUs.  Critical security updates will be available on Fermi series GPUs through January 2019.

I guess the last version that is compatible will 397.31 WHQL which was released on April 2018.

More info here:
[NVIDIACUSTHELP](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3473/%7E/eol-windows-driver-support-for-legacy-products)
[NVIDIAFORUMS](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/discover/273294/nvidia-dropping-fermi-support-and-32-bit/)
[NVIDIAFORUMS](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/discover/289117/gt-630-drivers-not-compatible-with-windows/)
[ANANDTECH.COM](https://www.anandtech.com/show/12624/nvidia-moves-fermi-to-legacy-ends-32bit-os-support)

Comment: Which driver did it find? You link just goes to the 'tell us what card you have' page. Inserting the information you give gets this page - https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/162105/en-us - 451.67  WHQL - which shows Win10/64 support.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm sorry sir, I've updated the question. I guess the link didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried removing the Nvidia driver that was installed through Windows Update before attempting to download the Nvidia driver?

Comment: No, but I've tried to install the driver I've downloaded on the official site of NVIDIA before the Windows Update does. @Ramhound

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the drivers from the executable using a program like 7-ZIP ([download here](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html)). Once installed, run 7-ZIP as an admin and navigate to the executable, right click, and select **Open Inside**.

[image]

On the next screen, you should see the contents of the EXE file. Right click on the folder named **Display.Driver**, select **Copy to...**, and put it on your desktop.

[image]

Next, go to your Device Manager > Display Adapters > double click the entry for the Graphics Card ("Microsoft Basic Display Adapter", most likely).

In the Properties window, **Update Driver**, select **Browse my computer for drivers**, and paste the path to the **Display.Driver** folder on your desktop and click **Next**.

[image]

Comment: Here is the result: https://ibb.co/SNr3HBy
When I checked on the GeForce Experience, the driver wasn't updated.

@SenorButtons

Comment: @SandrenTroyMilante - Uninstall and delete the drivers you currently have installed.  After you remove the drivers you should install the drivers as this answer recommends

Comment: @Ramhound I've uninstalled and deleted the drivers. I've restarted the computer because I can't see the display adapters section anymore. But when I've restarted, I can't see NVIDIA GeForce 630GT on the display adapters. I only see Microsoft Basic Display Adapter

Image here: https://ibb.co/kX3DdKW

Comment: @Sandren Troy Milante Assuming that that single entry is your integrated graphics card, it looks like you have successfully uninstalled the original Nvidia drivers. Are you still unable to install the newer drivers that you extracted from the executable? Have you also tried updating via GeForce again?

Comment: @SenorButtons Yes, I'm still unable to update my driver. I also tried to update via GeForce but the same error still occurred. I have no choice but to get the driver again from the windows update. I've encountered some windows bug where in explorer.exe keeps restarting while I'm scrolling at the start menu and search bars don't work properly. I've got those bugs after reinstalling NVIDIA drivers. I don't know if those two are linked but I've fixed thru system restore.

Can this be a issue between the W10 2004 build and NVIDIA driver? Anyways thank you for your efforts!

Comment: @Sandren Troy Milante No problem. Looking thru the GeForce Forums, it looks like you aren't the only to run into a problem like this. Keep us posted if  you can. I'd be curious to know how this shakes out.

Comment: As you wish sir! Anyways I've encountered more errors after this one. I've performed a system restore and let the windows update install what's recommended. So if you've encounter any questions like this, I would like to tell some info that only system restore and let windows update resolve this for now at W10 Build 2004. My W10 Build 1909 PC have the latest updates without any hassles. Also, I don't recommend updating to W10 Build 2004 due to many compatibility issues present. I guess we should wait until Microsoft releases a more stable update sooner or later. @SenorButtons